# casting unsigned to complex<int> causes sign-conversion warning

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Consider the following code:

```
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    unsigned u = 1u;
    auto result = static_cast<std::complex<int>>(u);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Werror -Wsign-conversion -o a.out source_file.cpp
```

Causes compile error

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:8:51: error: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘unsigned int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]
     auto result = static_cast<std::complex<int>>(u);
                                                   ^
```

clang reports a similar error

```
source_file.cpp:6:50: error: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'unsigned int' to 'const value_type' (aka 'const int') [-Werror,-Wsign-conversion]
    auto result = static_cast<std::complex<int>>(u);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~                    ^
```

The error does not make much sense at first sight, what am I missing?

Comment: Compiles successfully for me. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bRP59_)

Comment: _The error does not make much sense_ — Why do you think so? With `-Werror`, warning are treated as errors, which is exactly what you are getting.

Comment: @NutCracker your link leads to Not Found.

Comment: @misev no, it works fine

Comment: @DanielLangr I thought it makes no sense because it doesn't happen when casting unsigned to int (instead of complex<int>)

Comment: @NutCracker you forgot to add  -Wsign-conversion

Comment: @NutCracker You omitted the OP's flags `-Werror -Wsign-conversion`.

Comment: Yeah, have seen that now. Sry

Comment: @misev The warning is there alright, its for the same reason that `int i = u` gives the same warning

Comment: @darune but `int i = static_cast<int>(u)` works fine, so I'm mainly confused by the unclear discrepancy in behavior.

Comment: @misev The constructor of `std::complex<int>` has a first parameter of type `const int&`, which is initialized with `u` argument. This is where the problem occurs. If you write `static_cast<std::complex<int>>(static_cast<int>(u));`, then, then the [problem disappears](https://godbolt.org/z/YHywvF).

Comment: @misev that due to the cast - ie. you telling c++ that it's ok - you should not get a conversion warning *at the cast level*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a conversion warning not from the cast, but *from inside* construction of `std::complex`.

To 'fix' your example you should instead do:

```
auto result = std::complex<int>{static_cast<int>(u)};
```